# CMD How to set different variables for each search result

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

This code fix this with `Effective("flyer", 50%);` `Effective("flyer", 100%);`

```
@For /F "Tokens=1*" %%A In ('FindStr /I "Effective(\"flyer\"," "file.cfg"^|Find /V /N ""')Do @For /F "Tokens=2Delims=,%% " %%C In ("%%B")Do @Set "flyer%%A=%%C"
@Set flyer[
@Pause
```

How to Make it work with `Amount(5);` and other `Amount(10);`
With explain please if u can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would obviously modify the `Str`ing to `Find` with `FindStr`, i.e. change `"Effective(\"flyer\","` to `"Amount("`, then adjust your `Delim`iters from <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>  to <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> .

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*" %%A In ('FindStr /I "Amount(" "file.cfg"^|Find /V /N ""')Do @For /F "Tokens=2Delims=() " %%C In ("%%B")Do @Set "amount%%A=%%C"
@Set amount[
@Pause
```

As this is one of several questions related to the same task, I'd strongly recommend that you open a Command Prompt window, enter, `For /?`, `FindStr /?`, `Find /?` and `Set /?`, and read the output from each.

As a side note, you could shorten the code still further in this specific case and use `Find` only:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=[]() " %%A In ('Find /I /N "Amount("^<"file.cfg"')Do @Set "%%B[%%A]=%%C"
@Set Amount[
@Pause
```

The `Find` only code would be simple to adjust for searching for `ConstructionTime(` too:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=[]() " %%A In ('Find /I /N "ConstructionTime("^<"file.cfg"')Do @Set "%%B[%%A]=%%C"
@Set ConstructionTime[
@Pause
```